# Value Error Not Enough Values to Unpack in my API Request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm pulling data from my database and trying to pass it my web app via the API using python requests.  I've done this several times, but I'm having a hard time on this script.

It gives me "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

```
rpt_cursor = rpt_conn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT `field` FROM `db`.`table`;"""
rpt_cursor.execute(sql)

#Creating list of field names.
num_fields = len(rpt_cursor.description)
field_names = [i[0] for i in rpt_cursor.description]

# getting results and defining dict to load them into.
results = rpt_cursor.fetchall()
dictofemails = []

print('These are the SQL results....')
print(results)  # These look fine.

# Appending data to the dict.
for row in results:
    dictofdata.append(dict(zip(field_names,row)))

print('These are the dict results...')
print(dictofdata) # Once again this looks like a fine dict with a format of [{'field_name' : 'xyz'}, {'field_name' : 'abc'}].

api_request_url = 'https://api.domainname.com/api/list/' + str(target) +'/Api_Key/' + my_apikey

print('api_request_url')  # This looks fine.

response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=dictofdata)
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

Any clues you guys could give me would be appreciated.

Edit:

Traceback as requested....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "NGM_ListMaker_WeeklyBounceLoad.py", line 306, in <module>
response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=dictofemails)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 126, in put
return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 499, in prepare_body
body = self._encode_params(data)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 97, in _encode_params
for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Edit with the Answer:

The API was expecting a string instead of the list that I was passing it.   Changing the API call to data=str(dictofdata) was all that was needed.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should show the full traceback. We don't know what line is throwing the error.

Comment: parameter - data need to pass a dictionary not a list. That is all.

Comment: Close!  The API apparently wants it as a string not as a list.   Changing it to data=str(dictofdata).    Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API was expecting a string instead of the list I was trying to pass.

Change this...

response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=dictofdata)

to this...

response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=str(dictofdata))

Works fine now.  Thanks everyone.